# How to let an A href link in the menu bar when clicked, it opens a closed accordion in the body? - html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

how the first accordion could be opened when clicked on the a href named "open 1st accordion" and the same thing for the second a href?? The accordion itself works 100% right, I just want to access it from outside it's scope, when clickng on an a href button in the menu bar.

```js
$(".expand").on("click", function () {
    $(".right-arrow").text("+");
    $(".detail:visible").slideUp();
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){

        $(this).next().slideDown(200);
        $(this).find(".right-arrow").text("-");
    }
});
```

```css
/*Tips & Tricks Page*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#trickslist {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#trickslist ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #555;
}
#trickslist ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#trickslist ul:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#trickslist ul > li:hover {
    background: #efefef;
}
.expand {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tipstricks {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

span {
    font-size: 12.5px;
}
#left,#right{
    display: table;
}

.detail a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C0392B;
    border: 1px solid #C0392B;
    padding: 6px 10px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.detail {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 150px;
}
.detail span{
    margin: 0;
}
.right-arrow {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="""> Open 1st accordion </a> <br>
<a href="""> Open 2nd accordion </a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="accordion1">
        <div id="trickslist">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="tipstricks">Exploring your Motivations to Quit Tobacco</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">What to expect over time.</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Getting Ready: Strategies to conquer urges & set a quit date</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Quitting tobacco with medications</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Dealing with depression or stress</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Avoiding weight gain or alcohol</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Making your plan stick: relapse prevention</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Services.html (every a href in this menu should link to accordions in index.html and open them)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item" >
<a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Who We Are
</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="accord" href="">Our Services</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" id="nav">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="assets/images/name.png"/> </a>  
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="accord" href="">Our Clients</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="accord" href="" >Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the top tags `a`:

```
<a class="accord" href=""> Open 1st accordion </a> <br>
<a class="accord" href=""> Open 2nd accordion </a>
```

Next, using the `each()` method and the **index** parameter, write the logic of the click event on these `a` tags.

Use `event.preventDefault()` to disable the default behavior of the `a` tag.

And using the `trigger()` method, call click events on the `.expand` class using an `eq()` with the appropriate **index**:

```
$(".expand").eq(index).trigger('click');
```

As such, we get the following code. Just add it to your main code.

```
$('.accord').each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".expand").eq(index).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

### EDIT:

Modified the **jquery** code taking into account the `localStorage()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand").on("click", function () {
        $(".right-arrow").text("+");
        $(".detail:visible").slideUp();
        if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown(200);
            $(this).find(".right-arrow").text("-");
        }
    });

    let click_state = localStorage.getItem("click_state");
    let ind = localStorage.getItem("ind");

    if (click_state == 1) {
        $(".expand").eq(ind).trigger("click");

        localStorage.removeItem("click_state");
        localStorage.removeItem("ind");
    } else {
    }

    $(".accord").each(function (index) {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            localStorage.setItem("click_state", 1);
            localStorage.setItem("ind", index);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/*Tips & Tricks Page*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#trickslist {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#trickslist ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    color: #555;
}
#trickslist ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
#trickslist ul:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#trickslist ul > li:hover {
    background: #efefef;
}
.expand {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tipstricks {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

span {
    font-size: 12.5px;
}
#left,#right{
    display: table;
}

.detail a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C0392B;
    border: 1px solid #C0392B;
    padding: 6px 10px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.detail {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
    display: none;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 150px;
}
.detail span{
    margin: 0;
}
.right-arrow {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="accord" href=""> Open 1st accordion </a> <br>
<a class="accord" href=""> Open 2nd accordion </a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="accordion1">
        <div id="trickslist">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="tipstricks">Exploring your Motivations to Quit Tobacco</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">What to expect over time.</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Getting Ready: Strategies to conquer urges & set a quit date</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Quitting tobacco with medications</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Dealing with depression or stress</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Avoiding weight gain or alcohol</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Making your plan stick: relapse prevention</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @s-kuznetsov thank you it worked but one more thing plz, if I have these two a links but in another page and want them when clicked on to get back to this main page and open the accordions? hint: the another page has no accordions, it just have the same two a's

Comment: I am glad to help. Tell me pls, are your pages loading by ajax?

Comment: @s-kuznetsov no

Comment: If you are not using ajax, then you need to pass the click state of the link using `cookies` or `localStorage`.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov that's a bit hard right? im still a beginner 
is using ajax easier?

Comment: `Ajax` allows you to download content without reloading. I cannot advise you to advise this method, since I do not know the concept of your site. As for passing values through `localStorage`, it is **not difficult**, but it requires special attention, because you need to write additional code.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov can u please help me in this?

Comment: If I find you a similar example with `localStorage`, can you figure it out yourself? Or it will be better if you post a new question here on this topic.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov i'll figure it myself

Comment: @s-kuznetsov and how to do it with ajax plz?

Comment: First, you need to write an ajax method for loading pages into a container. How is content or pages on your site loaded? Show how the structure of your site looks like, pls.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov very simple html files, index.html & services.html

Comment: services.html has the same html composition (menu, footer, etc.) as index.html?

Comment: @s-kuznetsov yes

Comment: then it's better without ajax. Otherwise, you will have to redo the layout. Let me help you tomorrow, if there is time.

Comment: @s-kuznetsov  are u free please?

Comment: very busy now :(

Comment: Hi again. I made you a code with localStorage(). SO will not work here in the snippet (browser protection), but it will work well in your project. I apologize for a long time I could not give an answer. Was very very very busy.

Comment: s.kuznetsov thanks a lot but can u please tell me if I should place this code in both index.html and services.html? the <a> button is is services.html and it should hyperlink to a specific opened accordion in index.html

Comment: The fact is that the code assumes the presence of a separate custom js file.

Comment: s.kuznetsov ok lets assume I have created a js file and put the script in it, then what to do?

Comment: i've editted the question and added some of services.html code, please see it

Comment: Write the path to your file using the `<script>` tag, put this tag in the `<head>` tag of **both **html files. And your code will work. Like that - `<script src="your link"></script>`.

Comment: s.kuznetsov I know I ask too much but I really need help im sorry :( I put the code in a single js file and called it in both html files, but still in services.html it doesnt work. is the <a> in services.html class should be "accord" and href=" " ?

Comment: Yes, that tag `<a>` should be an `accord` class in `services.html`. I tested the code. Works for me. Did you specify the correct path to the js file?

Comment: it didnt work :( are u sure that <a> tag in services.html should be empty? and the js file should contain the code above from $(document).ready(function () { till the end right?

Comment: any help please? :(

Comment: i'm still stucked, it would be so much appreciated if u help me

Comment: @ramafleifel, But why don't you want to create a new question using my code. And then, you will get an answer faster.